# Help needed on SQL Query, Time out

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have this simple query, which is timing out. Any idea how to optimize it or any other way around?

```
SELECT 
b.SubscriberKey,
b.EmailAddress,
b.FName as FirstName,
b.LName as LastName,
o.EventDate
FROM [ABC] b WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN _open o WITH (NOLOCK) ON b.SubscriberKey = o.SubscriberKey
Where convert(date,getdate()) <= Dateadd(d,30,convert(date,o.EventDate))
```

Comment: You want _every_ open or just the most recent one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the most recent open per subscriber, I'd write it like this:

```sql
SELECT top 1 with ties
b.SubscriberKey,
b.EmailAddress,
b.FName as FirstName,
b.LName as LastName,
o.EventDate
FROM [ABC] b
INNER JOIN _open o ON o.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
Where o.isunique = 1
and o.eventDate >= convert(date, getDate()-30) 
order by row_number() over (partition by b.subscriberkey order by o.eventDate desc)
```

The `with (nolock)` has no impact in SFMC anymore.  And you should refrain from adding functions to the left side of your conditionals (aka make them [sargable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable/799616#799616)).  Also I'd include only unique opens to reduce the scope of records included.

Comment: Thanks Adam, this look great. So what's the use case of top 1 with ties is it you are using because of order by col?

Comment: Yes, if a subscriber has multiple rows in the results, only the first one is returned.